# Import XML files into Atlas MongoDB cluster

Tags: python, xml, export-to-csv, mongodb-atlas

My goal is to import over 400 XML files (about 1MB each) into Atlas MongDB.

I can import CSV files no problem. But I can't find a good way to convert multiple XML files to a single, flat CSV file.

Another way would be to convert each  XML to individual CSVs and then have Python to use my mongoimport command to import each csv one by one.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to store the xml itself in the mongo db or do you want to extract data from the xml and store that in your database?
If the second one: use the lxml module (https://lxml.de/) to parse your xml into a dict which you than can store in your database

Comment: Thanks Creolo. I think id rather import the XML direct into Atlas MongoDB, if possible (im really bad at Python)